# Quotes do not work in Netbeans

Tags: java, php, netbeans

The quotes `"` and `'` do not work in my NetBeans IDE 8.0.1. I tried different versios, but the results are the same.

I have to use this for projects for school. A strange thing is, this works on my laptop.

Any idea what I can do to solve this problem? I checked Google, but found nothing useful yet to solve it.
The KeyEventDebug also doesn't show the quotes when I type them, but any other character ain't a problem.
Link to KeyEventDebug: https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/editor/KeyEventDebug.jar

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Describe _do not work_.

Comment: What is your machine's locale, and what OS?

Comment: Do not work... They don't show up in the text-editor, pressing the key results in nothing. My machine has Windows 8.1 Pro and my machine's locale is 'Dutch(Netherlands)', the same as my laptop.

Comment: I have the same problem. A (almost) workaround for me is change the keyboard language forth and back again. BUT this works just for a while and the problem backs again. OBS: I use Ubuntu 14.04, international english keyboard (with deadkeys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution. I had a program running called PhraseExpress. Some of the key's I bound to the program prevented to display the characters in the program. I simply removed Netbeans from the PhraseExpress list and it worked like it should.